# Is xen a good choice for what I'm going to make?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, virtualization, xen

I want to build two machines inside a virtualization system like Xen, and I'm new with virtualization.

The first machine is a Debian 6 server, which runs forwadding and acts as a firewall and proxy.

The second is a Windows 7 machine. This machine needs to forward everything to the debian machine.

I need the Windows machine to be as smooth as virtualization can be, so my really question is: is Xen capable of virtualize windows at a good speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed of the virtualisation entirely depends onyour hardware, but take in mind that virtualised windows will never be as fast as baremetal windows.